# Did Archer cause the elevator to break?

Tags: plot-explanation, archer

In [Archer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1486217/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) S06E05, "Vision Quest", did Archer cause the elevator to break? I didn't quite understand what happened. Ray called Mallory using his cell phone and instead it called the elevator phone. Archer was trying to prevent Ray from calling Mallory obviously because he know it would call the elevator phone, but the recording was confusing. It made a joke about being stuck in an elevator. At that point everyone attacked Archer.

So, did Archer cause the elevator to break or did I miss a joke somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Archer Wikia](http://archer.wikia.com/wiki/Vision_Quest) it was both Archer and Ray's fault (emphasis mine):

> Suddenly, (Archer) shows up and calls for Ray to hold the door. Ray, pretending to press the "door open" button, repeatedly presses the "door close" button, but Archer forces the doors back with a mop. The group begins chatting, then bickering, then shouting, all the while unaware that, **through a combination of Ray and Archer's actions, the elevator has malfunctioned** until it overshoots the top floor, crashes into the car lift, and stalls.

Comment: Nice info, but doesn't address the phone redirection and the message about being stuck in an elevator

Comment: I think I have to rewatch the episode

Comment: I watched it recently and replayed it so I can hear the recording more clearly and I still can’t figure it out. It’s actually not even clear how the call was routed to the elevator in a way that makes sense.

Comment: @DarfNader not a lot of things make sense in Archer, see latest seasons...

Comment: @Luciano of course, as he is in a "state" (no spoilers). HJ Benjamin has stated in interviews some of the running gags come from things that are ad-libbed but sound good ("Paging Johnny Bench") but are otherwise meaningless at the time but then catch on because they can be interpreted to have meaning later (Johnny Bench, as a catcher, would have "big hands"). The "Are you or have you been trapped in an elevator?" bit with the zip-zap sounds of a radio commercial is so off the wall it defies logic, just as the groups subsequent outrage about it. Maybe it will forever be a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Archer always seems to be the "Go-To" when anything bad has happened, mainly cause it's usually his fault. So chances are good Archer did cause the elevator to break.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that was why everyone was angry at Archer.  Not to say that he did/didn't break the elevator, but I think what everyone was angry at him for was for breaking the elevator phone somehow by routing Mallory's incoming number to it, which meant they couldn't contact anyone for help, since 911 considered it not to be an emergency.

As for why he did this, it wasn't clear.  I would have sworn that in a different episode, he mentioned that he had done so for one of his voicemail pranks, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it was left intentionally vague.

We know Archer likes to rig phones in terrible ways (remember the mansion when he rigged all the lights and everything and even Kreiger was amazed).  That said, he may have just rigged the phone as part of another joke.

The ending implies Malory may have done it on purpose as a "team building exercise", but she claimed they were going to watch Vision Quest.

It's like the ending of season 5, we don't know for sure if it was Malory or Archer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a frequency in the show of the elevator being broken. It was said that they slammed into the motor at the top and thats what caused the malfunction. They attacked Archer because thanks to another of his pranks they had no way of getting out.